# Comme (d')énormes

Tags: grammaire, comparatifs

Bonjour,

Dans *Salammbô* :

> Au milieu, douze piédestaux de cuivre portaient chacun une grosse
> boule de verre, et des lueurs rougeâtres emplissaient confusément ces
> globes creux, *comme d'énormes* prunelles qui palpiteraient encore.

Est-ce que les deux formes sont correctes, *comme d'énormes* et *comme énormes* ?

Comment: Serait-il possible de nous dire pourquoi vous mettez en cause des formes comme cela qui suivent parfaitement la règle grammaticale? e-e, non.

Comment: Je ne connais pas la règle ici. Peut-on écrire comme d'énormes et comme érnormes sans aucun problème ?

Comment: @Lambie La forme n'est pas mise en cause, elle n'est tout simplement pas bien assimilée pour l'instant, mais c'est tout.

Comment: @LPH La forme n'est pas mise en cause?? comme de, des, d' etc., sont des  formes comparatives. comme e-e, n'est rien du tout. Pour comparer des choses, il faut l'article.

Comment: @Lambie Et pourtant j'ai trouvé sur Google des formules comparatives sans "de, des, d' etc.'" Si c'est rien du tout, pourquoi on écrit comme ça aussi ?

Comment: Tu as trouvé des **participes passés**? p.ex. Comm**e e**xténué de toutes forces? Sinon, donne-moi un exemple, stp.

Comment: @Lambie mettre en cause : incriminer, syn : accuser, attaquer, blamer, critiquer. Vous voyez bien que l'OP n'attaque rien, ne blame rien, ne critique rien. Il ne fait que chercher à savoir. Tenez-vous en à ce que vous lisez (Je crois vous avoir déjà dit ça, malheureusement).

Comment: @Lambie Qu'est-ce que c'est que cette notion de comparaison ? Ça n'a rien à voir dans ce cas. « J'étais comme exténué » est une tournure idiomatique dans laquelle l'article n'a rien à voir.

Comment: @LPH Tu n'as pas suivi la discussion. Il y a deux choses différentes!

Comment: Il serait bon de nous signalé que les exemples que tu donnes ne viennent pas de livres écrit en français. On perd beaucoup de temps avec; "J'ai trouvé x" sans aucun lien ou référence.

Comment: @Lambie Les exemples ont été donnés dans le seul but d'éclaircir mon doute. Désolé s'ils viennent des textes traduits. Je suppose, tout de même, que les traducteurs ont une bonne connaissance de la langue pour travailler dans ce métier. En tout cas, LPH a déjà répondu à la question.

Comment: En tout cas, comme j'ai dit dans mon premier commentaire et que lui, il dit dans sa première phrase, "comme énormes" ne va pas. Mais la raison c'est parce que: comme + de est un comparatif. Et on ne peut pas se passer de "de" pour/dans un comparatif.

Comment: QUE ET COMME MARQUEURS DE COMPARAISON
Catherine Fuchs, Nathalie Fournier https://halshs.archives-ouvertes.fr/halshs-00067924/file/Lexique_Que_comme_compar.pdf

Comment: @Lambie Le mot « article » ne figure pas dans cette parution de Fournier ; dire que le marqueur de comparaison est la raison semble inapproprié ; pourquoi spécialement le marqueur de comparaison ? Je crois qu'il faille se référer à un contexte grammatical plus général, le plus général étant  la nécessité d'utiliser un article en français, sauf cas exceptionnel.

Comment: @Lambie Je ne comprends pas pourquoi tu parles de livres traduits. *Salammbô* de Gustave Flaubert serait une (mauvaise) traduction ?

Comment: @jiliagre Je crois que Lambie se réfère aux exemples avec "comme e..." que j'ai donné sous la réponse de LPH.

Comment: @jlliagre Les **deux** phrases sont dans des traductions citées par ovide. Elles ne se trouvent pas **dans la question**.....Elles se trouvent dans les commentaires.

Comment: @Lambie Je ne vois aucune phrase citée dans les commentaires d'ovide. La seule phrase citée est celle de la question.

Comment: @jlliagre 1)  "et les sociétés humaines comme énormes machines infiniment hybrides dont le système". 2) "Aujourd'hui encore, adultes comme enfants perdus dans leur vie viennent à lui en espérant qu'il leur trouvera le livre salvateur." **Deux phrases citées par Ovide dans les commentaires**.

Comment: @Lambie Ah, d'accord. Il aurait été plus clair de mettre ton commentaire au bon endroit, en dessous de la réponse à laquelle le commentaire d'ovide était destiné et pas ailleurs.

Answer (score 2):

***Comme*** a de nombreux cas d'usage en français.

Dans le texte de Flaubert, c'est un comparatif. On pourrait dire :

> *les lueurs emplissent les globes creux **à la manière** d'énormes prunelles*.

***De*** est requis dans ce cas, sauf quelques expression figées (*Il pleut **comme** vache qui pisse*).

***Comme*** peut aussi servir de marqueur de catégorisation. C'est l'un des cas où l'on omet l'article :

> Je n'ai pas trouvé mieux **comme** restaurant.

On pourrait dire ici :

> Je n'ai pas trouvé mieux **en guise de** restaurant.

Il existe quantité d'autres usages de ***comme***, la longueur de son [entrée dans le TLFi](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/comme) en témoigne. Voir aussi *[Comme préposition ?](https://www.cairn.info/revue-travaux-de-linguistique-2002-1-page-69.htm)* Michel Pierrard, 2002.

Comment: Aussi, _Je n'ai pas trouvé mieux **en tant que** restaurant._

Answer (score 1):

Non, seule est correcte la forme dans le texte.

La raison est que ce mot, « de », est un article et qu'il n'est pas optionnel dans ce contexte grammatical.

> [**grammaire, Kalmbach**](http://research.jyu.fi/grfle/article-indefini.html)) Critères de variation
>
> L’ar­ti­cle in­dé­fi­ni est l’un des deux déterminants appelés « ar­ti­cles » dans la ter­mi­no­lo­gie grammaticale fran­çai­se. La for­me de l’ar­ti­cle in­dé­fi­ni peut varier selon les cri­tères sui­vants :
>
> 1 ) gen­re (mas­cu­lin/fé­mi­nin) et/ou nombre (singulier/pluriel) du nom,
> 2 ) mode de représenta­tion du ré­fé­rent du nom (comptable ou massif),
> 3 ) structure de la phra­se (ad­jec­tif an­té­po­sé, phra­se né­ga­ti­ve, pré­po­si­tion de).
>
> [image]

On dirait cependant « **des** prunelles énormes ».

Comment: Merci. J'ai trouvé sur Google des formules avec "comme énormes". Par exemple : "et les sociétés humaines comme énormes machines infiniment hybrides dont le système". Est-ce incorrect ?

Comment: @ovide Dans ce bout de texte « comme » signifie « en tant que »  et non « à la manière de ».   Par exemple dans « Il l'a engagé comme secrétaire. » il ne faudra jamais d'article. Cf. : « Il travaille comme secrétaire. / Il travaille comme un secrétaire. », (en tant que/de la même manière que le font les secrétaires).

Comment: D'accord, mais dans ce cas : "Aujourd'hui encore, adultes comme enfants perdus dans leur vie viennent à lui en espérant qu'il leur trouvera le livre salvateur." [Source : https://actualitte.com/article/48720/edition/le-maitre-des-livres-umiharu-shinohara-merveilleuse-litterature-jeunesse] Comme ne fonctionne pas ici dans le sens de "à la manière de" ?

Comment: @ovide PRIMAVERA GOMES CALDAS est sûrement hispanophone. En espagnol, ça marche: **como enormes máquinas**....mais pas en français.

Comment: @ovide Dans le contexte « Aujourd'hui encore, adultes comme enfants perdus … » les articles sont optionnels. ex. simple : « Après avoir mis (les) couteaux et (les) fourchettes à leur place elle posa les verres devant les assiettes. ». Les deux sont omis ensembles, pas d'autre possibilité.

Comment: @LPH Merci beaucoup ! Je ne savais pas.

Comment: Vignette du livre Le maître des livres T.1 - Umiharu Shinohara
Le maître des livres T.1 Umiharu Shinohara
Date de parution : Octobre 2014 Éditeur: KOMIKKU Lá aussi, il s'agit d'une **traduction**. Normalement, on dirait: les adultes et les enfants perdus dans ce contexte précis.

Comment: @Lambie L'omission est aussi normale, et elle peut même être utilisée dans la langue parlée.

Comment: @ovide J'ai oublié un détail dans votre commentaire (« Comme » n'a-t-il pas le sens de « à la manière de » dans « Aujourd'hui … » ?). Non, ce n'est pas le sens selon lequel on doit comprendre « comme » ; TLFi : [Comme marque la conformité] Synon. ainsi que.